# how to get the current thing in this code

Tags: python

this is my code :

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a="aaa"
        self.b='bbb'

aa=a()
x=['a','b','c']
for i in x:
    print aa.get(i)
```

it show error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 10, in <module>
    print aa['a']
AttributeError: a instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

what can i do ,

thanks

**updated:**

i want print 'aaa' and 'bbb'

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking here.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Does the class a have a get method?

Comment: according to the [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and common practice, words in class names should be capitalized. That is, `class A()` rather than `class a()`. It isn't in the style guide, but an empty base class specifier is usually elided (`class A` rather than `class A()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `getattr(aa, i)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function or define a [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method for class `a` (though to implement it, you'll probably end up using `getattr`).

It looks like the error message was generated by [different code](http://sscce.org) where you were trying `aa[i]` rather than `aa.get(i)`, which means (besides that the sample isn't representative) defining `a.__getattr__` won't work with the sample code, though it would work if you use `aa[i]` instead of `aa.get(i)`.